# C++ Standard Library approach to removing one of a pair of items in a list that satisfy a criterion

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, iterator, std

Imagine you have an `std::list` with a set of values in it. For demonstration's sake, we'll say it's just `std::list<int>`, but in my case they're actually 2D points. Anyway, I want to remove *one of a pair of* `int`s (or points) which satisfy some sort of distance criterion. My question is how to approach this as an iteration that doesn't do more than O(N^2) operations.

**Example**

Source is a list of `int`s containing:

`{ 16, 2, 5, 10, 15, 1, 20 }`

If I gave this a distance criterion of `1` (i.e. no item in the list should be within `1` of any other), I'd like to produce the following output:

`{ 16, 2, 5, 10, 20 }` if I iterated forward *or*

`{ 20, 1, 15, 10, 5 }` if I iterated backward

I feel that there must be some awesome way to do this, but I'm stuck with this double loop of iterators and trying to erase items while iterating through the list.

Comment: Your example may have oversimplified the problem. The solution for a sorted list of 1-dimensional points is clearly O(N). Maybe not so much for 2D.

Comment: How is it clearly O(N)? Don't you have to compare each item against all others in the list? The list is not guaranteed to be sorted like the example given above happens to be.

Comment: As I said, the solution for a **sorted list of 1-dim points** is O(N). If your general case includes an unsorted list or multi-dimensional ponts, then *your example may have oversimplified the problem.*

Comment: It's not necessarily sorted. I thought it would be easier for people to understand if I sorted the numbers in the example, but I didn't say anything about sorting in the question. I'll rearrange the ordering in the problem.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and and assert that you can't do better than O(n^2). Since there is no ordering possible among 2D points, you have to compute every pair-wise distance. You can find `std::` algorithms to hide the complexity in your source code, but that won't change the big-Oh.

Comment: I'm also not asking for better than O(N^2). I said I'm looking at how to approach it in a way that doesn't *do more than* O(N^2) operations.

Comment: I kind of knew that in advance -- the problem is that I'm having trouble even writing the "naive" approach (especially with the reverse iteration). If somebody posted that, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: After the modification, if iterated in fw mode list should not be { 16, 2, 5, 10, 20} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a map of "regions", basically, a `std::map<coordinates/len, std::vector<point>>`.
Add each point to it's region, and each of the 8 neighboring regions `O(N*logN)`.  Run the "nieve" algorithm on each of these smaller lists (technically `O(N^2)` unless theres a maximum density, then it becomes `O(N*density)`).  Finally: On your origional list, iterate through each `point`, and if it has been removed from *any* of the 8 mini-lists it was put in, remove it from the list.  `O(n)`

With no limit on density, this is `O(N^2)`, and slow.  But this gets faster and faster the more spread out the points are.  If the points are somewhat evenly distributed in a known boundary, you can switch to a two dimensional array, making this *significantly* faster, and if there's a constant limit to the density, that *technically* makes this a `O(N)` algorithm.

That is how you sort a list of two variables by the way.  The grid/map/2dvector thing.

[EDIT] You mentioned you were having trouble with the "nieve" method too, so here's that:

```
template<class iterator, class criterion>
iterator RemoveCriterion(iterator begin, iterator end, criterion criter) {
    iterator actend = end;
    for(iterator L=begin; L != actend; ++L) {
        iterator R(L);
        for(++R; R != actend;) {
            if (criter(*L, *R) {
                iterator N(R); 
                std::rotate(R, ++N, actend);
                --actend;
            } else
                ++R;
        }
    }
    return actend;
}
```

This should work on linked lists, vectors, and similar containers, and works in reverse.  Unfortunately, it's kinda slow due to not taking into account the properties of linked lists.  It's possible to make *much* faster versions that only work on linked lists in a specific direction.  Note that the return value is important, like with the other mutating algorithms.  It can only alter contents of the container, not the container itself, so you'll have to erase all elements after the return value when it finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Cubbi had the best answer, though he deleted it for some reason:

> Sounds like it's a sorted list, in which case std::unique will do the job of removing the second element of each pair:

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
    std::list<int> data = {1,2,5,10,15,16,20};
    std::unique_copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
                    [](int n, int m){return abs(n-m)<=1;});
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> demo: https://ideone.com/OnGxk

That trivially extends to other types -- either by changing `int` to something else, or by defining a template:

```
template<typename T> void remove_close(std::list<T> &data, int distance)
{
    std::unique_copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
                    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "),
                    [distance](T n, T m){return abs(n-m)<=distance;});
    return data;
}
```

Which will work for any type that defines `operator -` and `abs` to allow finding a distance between two objects.

Comment: You have to call `std::sort` on it first, but that still is less than `O(N^2)` operations, so still good.

Comment: @MooingDuck Maybe I'm dense, but how does one sort a list of 2D points?

Comment: @Rob You can't that easily, I think. That's why you assumed correctly that the question's example oversimplified the real problem.

Comment: Well, for any type that doesn't have a well-defined global ordering, the question isn't well defined and there are many possible ways to do it (which will give you different answers).  For 2D points, you can do: sort on X, remove_close, sort on Y, remove_close; or a variety of other ways.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I can think of two ways to implement "Sort on X, remove_close, sort on Y, remove_close".  One does twice as much work as needed, and the other doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As a mathematician I am pretty sure there is no 'awesome' way to approaching this problem for an unsorted list. It seems to me that it is a logical necessity to check the criterion for any one element against all previous elements selected in order to determine whether insertion is viable or not. There may be a number of ways to optimize this, depending on the size of the list and the criterion.

Perhaps you could maintain a bitset based on the criterion. E.g. suppose abs(n-m)<1) is the criterion. Suppose the first element is of size 5. This is carried over into the new list. So flip bitset[5] to 1. Then, when you encounter an element of size 6, say, you need only test

```
!( bitset[5] | bitset[6] | bitset[7])
```

This would ensure no element is within magnitude 1 of the resulting list. This idea may be difficult to extend for more complicated(non discrete) criterions however.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
struct IsNeighbour : public std::binary_function<int,int,bool>
{
    IsNeighbour(int dist)
        : distance(dist) {}
    bool operator()(int a, int b) const
        { return abs(a-b) <= distance; }
    int distance;
};

std::list<int>::iterator iter = lst.begin();
while(iter != lst.end())
{
    iter = std::adjacent_find(iter, lst.end(), IsNeighbour(some_distance)));
    if(iter != lst.end())
        iter = lst.erase(iter);
}
```

This should have O(n). It searches for the first pair of neighbours (which are at maximum `some_distance` away from each other) and removes the first of this pair. This is repeated (starting from the found item and not from the beginning, of course) until no pairs are found anymore.

**EDIT:** Oh sorry, you said **any other** and not just its next element. In this case the above algorithm only works for a sorted list. So you should sort it first, if neccessary.

You can also use `std::unique` instead of this custom loop above:

```
lst.erase(std::unique(lst.begin(), lst.end(), IsNeighbour(some_distance), lst.end());
```

but this removes the second item of each equal pair, and not the first, so you may have to reverse the iteration direction if this matters.

For 2D points instead of ints (1D points) it is not that easy, as you cannot just sort them by their euclidean distance. So if your real problem is to do it on 2D points, you might rephrase the question to point that out more clearly and remove the oversimplified int example.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculated O(n)? On a list with no neighbors, won't `IsNeighbor` be called `n*(n-1)/2` times? The first call to `adjacent_find` calls `IsNeighbor()` `n` times, the next call to `adjacent_find` calls `IsNeighbor()` `n-1` times, etc.

Comment: @Rob No, the first call calls `IsNeighbour` n times and finds no neighbours. It therefore returns `lst.end` and the outer loop also stops. We always do the `adjacent_find` only the rest of the list, which gets smaller and smaller (at least by 1 if it contains only neighbours and by n if it contains no neighbours).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, as long as you don't mind making copies of the data, but if it's just a pair of integer/floats, that should be pretty low-cost. You're making n^2 comparisons, but you're using std::algorithm and can declare the input vector const.

```
//calculates the distance between two points and returns true if said distance is 
//under its threshold
bool isTooClose(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs, int threshold = 1);     
vector<Point>& vec; //the original vector, passed in
vector<Point>& out; //the output vector, returned however you like

for(b = vec.begin(), e = vec.end(); b != e; b++) {
    Point& candidate = *b;

    if(find_if(out.begin(),
               out.end(),
               bind1st(isTooClose, candidate)) == out.end())
    {//we didn't find anyone too close to us in the output vector. Let's add!
        out.push_back(candidate);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also make `isTooClose()` a functor object with the threshold as state input at construction.

Answer (score -3):

std::list<>.erase(remove_if(...)) using functors

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

Update(added code):

```
struct IsNeighbour : public std::unary_function<int,bool>
{
  IsNeighbour(int dist)
    : m_distance(dist), m_old_value(0){}
  bool operator()(int a)
    { 
      bool result = abs(a-m_old_value) <= m_distance; 
      m_old_value = a; 
      return result;
    }
  int m_distance;
  int m_old_value;
};

main function...
std::list<int> data = {1,2,5,10,15,16,20};
data.erase(std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(),  IsNeighbour(1)), data.end());
```

Comment: What about `std::unique` instead of `std::remove_if`, as a stateful functor is often not a good idea (although in this case it might work, but is just not neccessary).

Comment: "removes second item" - you're right, indeed. "readablity will be altered" - don't think so.

Comment: "don't think so" If a second developer sees the code what will think? *maybe that from list are erased value-duplicated elements?

Comment: No, he won't think that when he sees the predicate. Using `std` algorithms only in the strictest sense of their names extremely limits their applicability, making things like `std::inner_product` nearly useless. What do you think the custom functor arguments are for?